# Iterar sobre fórmula en Excel

Tags: excel, microsoft-office, office365, libreoffice-calc

Tengo 11 hojas en excel con distintos valores sobre ingresos, en una de ellas están las ventas. Necesito calcular en una hoja nueva la correlación de cada una de esos valores con las ventas.
Lo que hice es lo siguiente

```
=COEF.DE.CORREL('1'!$D$5:$V$5;'ventas'!$C$2:$U$2)
```

Lo que necesito es cambiar el `'1'` de la fórmula de tal forma que cuando arrastro hacia el costado la celda para copiar la fórmula me cambie a

```
=COEF.DE.CORREL('2'!$D$5:$V$5;'ventas'!$C$2:$U$2)
```

```
=COEF.DE.CORREL('3'!$D$5:$V$5;'ventas'!$C$2:$U$2)
```

y así sucesivamente hasta que llegué a 10

Comment: Combina tu fórmula con la función [INDIRECTO](https://support.office.com/es-es/article/indirecto-funci%C3%B3n-indirecto-474b3a3a-8a26-4f44-b491-92b6306fa261) y la función COLUMNA, para crear un rango indirecto a cada una de las páginas

Comment: @ElierSánchezE-Infantes puede especificar la fórmula ?

Comment: Pon un ejemplo sencillo de tus datos y le echo un ojo, porque influye la posición de la celda en la que metes tu fórmula

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar la función COLUMN() o COLUMNA() restando una constante que sea igual valor numérico de la columna de la izquierda de tu primera celda con fórmula. Entonces copia la fórmula a las celdas de la derecha.

Comment: Intento usar la siguiente formular pero me salta error ```=COEF.DE.CORREL(CONCAT("'";COLUMNA(B2);"'";!$D$5:$V$5;'ventas'!$C$2:$U$2))```